# Edit String using HTML5 only

Tags: html

Is it possible to edit a string in HTML5 only without JS?? Please, let me know if its possible.

I am currently working on a template where I have to pass a part of string to a Flask view, I know how to do it in flask, but I am working on someone else code and don't want to modify it, just want to pass the desired parameters

Comment: No. HTML is not a programming language; it doesn't have any way to manipulate data.

Comment: To the anonymouse downvoters, please don't downvote people just because you know this to be a question that is off-target. People come here to learn. It is also rude to downvote without explaining why.